# timezone conversion in php is not changing the date value

Tags: php, timezone

I have the following code...

```
    $stored_date = date_format(date_create('now'), 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
    echo 'Stored date: ' . $stored_date . "<br/>";

    $user_timezone = 'Australia/Brisbane';
```

I would like to convert $stored_date (which was created based on the server's timezone to a date or a string representation of the date based on $user_timezone.

I would like to do that using procedural PHP code rather than OO code.

I have tried..

```
   date_create($stored_date, timezone_open($user_timezone));
```

but that doesn't seem to to give a correct answer.

if `$stored_date is '2011-11-15 23:45:35'` with the server's timezone being 'America/Toronto' the result I'm getting is the same '2011-11-15 23:45:35'.

however, `date_create('now', timezone_open($user_timezone));` seems to work and give the correct date as per the $user_timezone.

any ideas on what i'm doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should try this. this had been worked for me.

```
$time = date_format(date_create('now'), 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
$tz = "Australia/Brisbane";

// create the DateTimeZone object for later
$dtzone = new DateTimeZone($tz);
// now create the DateTime object for this time and user time zone
$dtime = new DateTime($time,$dtzone);
// print the timestamp
$timestamp = $dtime->format('U');

//ultimate time according to timezone you have specified              
$time_final = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s",$timestamp);
```

hope this will help you.

here is the list of PHP timezones:

```
            'Kwajalein' => '(GMT-12:00) International Date Line West',
    'Pacific/Midway' => '(GMT-11:00) Midway Island',
    'Pacific/Samoa' => '(GMT-11:00) Samoa',
    'Pacific/Honolulu' => '(GMT-10:00) Hawaii',
    'America/Anchorage' => '(GMT-09:00) Alaska',
    'America/Los_Angeles' => '(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US &amp; Canada)',
    'America/Tijuana' => '(GMT-08:00) Tijuana, Baja California',
    'America/Denver' => '(GMT-07:00) Mountain Time (US &amp; Canada)',
    'America/Chihuahua' => '(GMT-07:00) Chihuahua',
    'America/Mazatlan' => '(GMT-07:00) Mazatlan',
    'America/Phoenix' => '(GMT-07:00) Arizona',
    'America/Regina' => '(GMT-06:00) Saskatchewan',
    'America/Tegucigalpa' => '(GMT-06:00) Central America',
    'America/Chicago' => '(GMT-06:00) Central Time (US &amp; Canada)',
    'America/Mexico_City' => '(GMT-06:00) Mexico City',
    'America/Monterrey' => '(GMT-06:00) Monterrey',
    'America/New_York' => '(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US &amp; Canada)',
    'America/Bogota' => '(GMT-05:00) Bogota',
    'America/Lima' => '(GMT-05:00) Lima',
    'America/Rio_Branco' => '(GMT-05:00) Rio Branco',
    'America/Indiana/Indianapolis' => '(GMT-05:00) Indiana (East)',
    'America/Caracas' => '(GMT-04:30) Caracas',
    'America/Halifax' => '(GMT-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)',
    'America/Manaus' => '(GMT-04:00) Manaus',
    'America/Santiago' => '(GMT-04:00) Santiago',
    'America/La_Paz' => '(GMT-04:00) La Paz',
    'America/St_Johns' => '(GMT-03:30) Newfoundland',
    'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires' => '(GMT-03:00) Georgetown',
    'America/Sao_Paulo' => '(GMT-03:00) Brasilia',
    'America/Godthab' => '(GMT-03:00) Greenland',
    'America/Montevideo' => '(GMT-03:00) Montevideo',
    'Atlantic/South_Georgia' => '(GMT-02:00) Mid-Atlantic',
    'Atlantic/Azores' => '(GMT-01:00) Azores',
    'Atlantic/Cape_Verde' => '(GMT-01:00) Cape Verde Is.',
    'Europe/Dublin' => '(GMT) Dublin',
    'Europe/Lisbon' => '(GMT) Lisbon',
    'Europe/London' => '(GMT) London',
    'Africa/Monrovia' => '(GMT) Monrovia',
    'Atlantic/Reykjavik' => '(GMT) Reykjavik',
    'Africa/Casablanca' => '(GMT) Casablanca',
    'Europe/Belgrade' => '(GMT+01:00) Belgrade',
    'Europe/Bratislava' => '(GMT+01:00) Bratislava',
    'Europe/Budapest' => '(GMT+01:00) Budapest',
    'Europe/Ljubljana' => '(GMT+01:00) Ljubljana',
    'Europe/Prague' => '(GMT+01:00) Prague',
    'Europe/Sarajevo' => '(GMT+01:00) Sarajevo',
    'Europe/Skopje' => '(GMT+01:00) Skopje',
    'Europe/Warsaw' => '(GMT+01:00) Warsaw',
    'Europe/Zagreb' => '(GMT+01:00) Zagreb',
    'Europe/Brussels' => '(GMT+01:00) Brussels',
    'Europe/Copenhagen' => '(GMT+01:00) Copenhagen',
    'Europe/Madrid' => '(GMT+01:00) Madrid',
    'Europe/Paris' => '(GMT+01:00) Paris',
    'Africa/Algiers' => '(GMT+01:00) West Central Africa',
    'Europe/Amsterdam' => '(GMT+01:00) Amsterdam',
    'Europe/Berlin' => '(GMT+01:00) Berlin',
    'Europe/Rome' => '(GMT+01:00) Rome',
    'Europe/Stockholm' => '(GMT+01:00) Stockholm',
    'Europe/Vienna' => '(GMT+01:00) Vienna',
    'Europe/Minsk' => '(GMT+02:00) Minsk',
    'Africa/Cairo' => '(GMT+02:00) Cairo',
    'Europe/Helsinki' => '(GMT+02:00) Helsinki',
    'Europe/Riga' => '(GMT+02:00) Riga',
    'Europe/Sofia' => '(GMT+02:00) Sofia',
    'Europe/Tallinn' => '(GMT+02:00) Tallinn',
    'Europe/Vilnius' => '(GMT+02:00) Vilnius',
    'Europe/Athens' => '(GMT+02:00) Athens',
    'Europe/Bucharest' => '(GMT+02:00) Bucharest',
    'Europe/Istanbul' => '(GMT+02:00) Istanbul',
    'Asia/Jerusalem' => '(GMT+02:00) Jerusalem',
    'Asia/Amman' => '(GMT+02:00) Amman',
    'Asia/Beirut' => '(GMT+02:00) Beirut',
    'Africa/Windhoek' => '(GMT+02:00) Windhoek',
    'Africa/Harare' => '(GMT+02:00) Harare',
    'Asia/Kuwait' => '(GMT+03:00) Kuwait',
    'Asia/Riyadh' => '(GMT+03:00) Riyadh',
    'Asia/Baghdad' => '(GMT+03:00) Baghdad',
    'Africa/Nairobi' => '(GMT+03:00) Nairobi',
    'Asia/Tbilisi' => '(GMT+03:00) Tbilisi',
    'Europe/Moscow' => '(GMT+03:00) Moscow',
    'Europe/Volgograd' => '(GMT+03:00) Volgograd',
    'Asia/Tehran' => '(GMT+03:30) Tehran',
    'Asia/Muscat' => '(GMT+04:00) Muscat',
    'Asia/Baku' => '(GMT+04:00) Baku',
    'Asia/Yerevan' => '(GMT+04:00) Yerevan',
    'Asia/Yekaterinburg' => '(GMT+05:00) Ekaterinburg',
    'Asia/Karachi' => '(GMT+05:00) Karachi',
    'Asia/Tashkent' => '(GMT+05:00) Tashkent',
    'Asia/Kolkata' => '(GMT+05:30) Calcutta',
    'Asia/Colombo' => '(GMT+05:30) Sri Jayawardenepura',
    'Asia/Katmandu' => '(GMT+05:45) Kathmandu',
    'Asia/Dhaka' => '(GMT+06:00) Dhaka',
    'Asia/Almaty' => '(GMT+06:00) Almaty',
    'Asia/Novosibirsk' => '(GMT+06:00) Novosibirsk',
    'Asia/Rangoon' => '(GMT+06:30) Yangon (Rangoon)',
    'Asia/Krasnoyarsk' => '(GMT+07:00) Krasnoyarsk',
    'Asia/Bangkok' => '(GMT+07:00) Bangkok',
    'Asia/Jakarta' => '(GMT+07:00) Jakarta',
    'Asia/Brunei' => '(GMT+08:00) Beijing',
    'Asia/Chongqing' => '(GMT+08:00) Chongqing',
    'Asia/Hong_Kong' => '(GMT+08:00) Hong Kong',
    'Asia/Urumqi' => '(GMT+08:00) Urumqi',
    'Asia/Irkutsk' => '(GMT+08:00) Irkutsk',
    'Asia/Ulaanbaatar' => '(GMT+08:00) Ulaan Bataar',
    'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur' => '(GMT+08:00) Kuala Lumpur',
    'Asia/Singapore' => '(GMT+08:00) Singapore',
    'Asia/Taipei' => '(GMT+08:00) Taipei',
    'Australia/Perth' => '(GMT+08:00) Perth',
    'Asia/Seoul' => '(GMT+09:00) Seoul',
    'Asia/Tokyo' => '(GMT+09:00) Tokyo',
    'Asia/Yakutsk' => '(GMT+09:00) Yakutsk',
    'Australia/Darwin' => '(GMT+09:30) Darwin',
    'Australia/Adelaide' => '(GMT+09:30) Adelaide',
    'Australia/Canberra' => '(GMT+10:00) Canberra',
    'Australia/Melbourne' => '(GMT+10:00) Melbourne',
    'Australia/Sydney' => '(GMT+10:00) Sydney',
    'Australia/Brisbane' => '(GMT+10:00) Brisbane',
    'Australia/Hobart' => '(GMT+10:00) Hobart',
    'Asia/Vladivostok' => '(GMT+10:00) Vladivostok',
    'Pacific/Guam' => '(GMT+10:00) Guam',
    'Pacific/Port_Moresby' => '(GMT+10:00) Port Moresby',
    'Asia/Magadan' => '(GMT+11:00) Magadan',
    'Pacific/Fiji' => '(GMT+12:00) Fiji',
    'Asia/Kamchatka' => '(GMT+12:00) Kamchatka',
    'Pacific/Auckland' => '(GMT+12:00) Auckland',
    'Pacific/Tongatapu' => '(GMT+13:00) Nukualofa'
```

Comment: Thanks Amit. my second question is this: is there a way to use the time zone code UM5, UM6, etc... with the above code instead of the php timezones line "Australia/Brisbane", ....? the reason being is that I already have the UMx timezone setup in a drop down list but can't find the equivalent drop down for the PHP timezones.